# Viewing SWF files in Firefox 9

Tags: firefox, flash, swf

I can't find a way to instruct Firefox 9 to open .swf files that were downloaded through a direct link to the file. It just prompts the Download window. In Options | Applications there seems to exist no way of associating the "View in Firefox" option to swf files.

With the Flash plugin installed, if I drag-drop a swf file inside a Firefox window, it will open the animation as expected. So I guess there should be a way of applying this behavior to the action of downloading swf files. Any suggestions? Thanks.